# Auto remove ending space of any text of EditText

Tags: java, android-studio

**Description**

I am developing one app in which I have registration page. Inside registration page, I am doing registration by getting user's full name and mobile number.

**Problem**

While getting user's full name in edit text sometimes the user is pressing space bar after typing his/her name.

I don't need space in my database after typing any text white user.

Comment: [.trim()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#trim())

Answer (score 1):

`.trim()` would remove whitespaces from the input, but you should probably then use two inputs, one for first name and one for last name

```
val string = "Bobby  "
val trimmed = string.trim()
```

Trimmed = "Bobby"

Answer (score 0):

not quite sure how your structure works, but if I understand the question correctly you just need a while loop going backwards from the end of the string checking to see if it is a space, if it is, remove it.

This assumes your input contains both first and last name, and only removes the whitespace at the end.

something like this should work:

```
Sting input = "input ";
while (input.charAt(input.length()-1) == ' '){
        input = input.substring(0, input.length()-1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would also recommend that you implement some kind of validations. For example, for an only whitespaces(spaces, tabs, new lines, etc...) input.

An example:

1. Get the UI element, in which the user will type:

`EditText firstName = requireActivity().findViewById(R.id.registerFirstName);`

2. Take the string value of the user's input and validate it as you wish:

`String firstNameStr = firstName.getText().toString();`

`if (firstNameStr.trim().equals("")) { Make a Toast or something }`

This way you are certain there are no extra whitespaces and the input is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

Use `string.trim()`

why to use trim()

> The trim() method in Java String is a built-in function that
> eliminates leading and trailing spaces. The Unicode value of space
> character is '\u0020'. The trim() method in java checks this Unicode
> value before and after the string, if it exists then removes the
> spaces and returns the omitted string.